# Where can I edit multi-cursor of xcode?

Tags: xcode

I want to edit a multi-cursor (^ + shift + click) of Xcode but I don't find the option to edit it. Anybody know where is it? 
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean edit the cursor?  Change the shape of the cursor, move it to a different place if you mis-clicked, something else...?

Comment: @bg2b I want to say what I want to edit the keys to execute the multi-cursor. Actually the multi-cursor execute when I press (^ + shift + click) and I want to change it by (option + shift + click) but I don't find the preferences to change it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to replace <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-click with <kbd>option</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-click. I don't believe there is any way to do that.

(My original answer, outlining how multiple cursors work, is below.)

---

If you’re talking about multiple cursors, you do it with <kbd>option</kbd>-click and drag.

For example, I wanted to add some spacing in the definition of this array:

[image]

This is #32 in Hacking with Swift’s [Xcode tips and tricks](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/166/xcode-tips-and-tricks-part-one).

(That having been said, Hacking with Swift uses example of the writing of an memberwise `init` method. That is something probably more easily achieved with “Editor” » “Refactor” » “Generate Memberwise Initializer”.)

---

The <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-click is for adding a cursor. E.g., in this example, I “accidentally” missed a cursor on the first line, so I <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-clicked on first line to add the missing cursor:

[image]

And if you <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-click on an existing cursor, it will remove it, effectively toggling the various cursors.

Comment: I know to do it but I want to edit the keys to execute the multi-cursor. For example,  actually the multi-cursor execute when I press (control + shift + click) and I want to change it by (option + shift + click) but I don't find the preferences to change it. Thanks

Comment: So, you want to replace control-shift-click with option-shift-click? I know of no way to do that.